# "TS1005: ',' expected.", Error

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a small test with jest and fast-check in vscode with Typescript 2.9.2 and I am getting the error "TS1005: ',' expected.", and [TS] ',' expected on the last line.
maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem like this code is missing anything?

```
test("up", () => {
    fc.assert(fc.property(fc.integer(), (a) => {
        const currentCount = initialState.count
        Actions.up(a)(initialState)
        expect(initialState.count).toEqual(currentCount + a)
    })
})
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error message based n the above code?
thanks..

Comment: Aren't you missing the closing parenthesis of the `fc.assert` call?

Comment: Your `fc.assert` call is missing its closing parenthesis.

Comment: Ha! Cant believe I actually missed that. Thanks guys....